# Forcing yarn to "refetch" a package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

I have a project that uses a UIKit. The Main project and UI Kit is all in Typescript and React.

Both the main project and the uikit are hosted in git.

In the main project t have a dependency line for the UIKIT that fetches the repo from github.
All this works fine.

When I need to make changes to the uikit, I make change in the code, then run the build steps and upload to git (on a dev branch)

In the main project t then modify the dependency link for the project
I will change it from
"@something-libs/uikit": "somegit/someprojectuikit",
to this (add the branch name at the end)
"@something-libs/uikit": "somegit/someprojectuikit#dev",

this works fine and when I run yarn install, it fetches the latest version of the dependency.

Now, say I need to make another change? I do that and upload to git.

The changes are then not reflected in the main project because yarn is not fetching the latest version. As a work around y just change the link back to the old version without the #dev part, rerun yarn install and then change it back to "@something-libs/uikit": "somegit/someprojectuikit#dev" and rerun install again.

Any suggestions how i can tell yarn "hey, the package has changed, go fetch it again"

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for how to solve this, the easiest one is to use the command

```sh
yarn upgrade {package_name}
```

In your case, the command will look like this:

```sh
yarn upgrade @something-libs/uikit
```

After running the `upgrade` command, you will get the latest commit from your github repository in `node_modules/@something-libs/uikit`